# Update url query upon form submission

Tags: forms

I am trying to append a variable on the URL through a custom submit function. Is that possible?

My issue is that I am coming to the node/%/delete from different pages. I want to modify the delete form if the user comes to it from the node/%/edit. How can I detect this?

As @Clive suggested I'll try to add a query param in the following structure:

```
actions (Array, 5 elements)
  #type (String, 7 characters ) actions
  submit (Array, 5 elements)
  preview (Array, 5 elements)
  delete (Array, 4 elements)
    #type (String, 6 characters ) submit
    #value (String, 6 characters ) Delete
    #weight (Integer) 15
```

Comment: Don't - basing logic on referrers is hit and miss and violates a RESTful web...instead, alter the edit form and change the url of the delete link to add a URL parameter to the delete URL, then alter the delete form to check for that parameter

Comment: Awesome input!How can I do that?

Comment: hook_form_alter for both, the delete link is in `$form['actions']` I think. Just on mobile so can't put code samples in I'm afraid

Comment: Cool!How could I add the param on the above structure?

Comment: @Clive can you explain it more, I couldn't understand, as far as I know pressing delete button from node edit form will take you to a confirmation page, which is a redirect, and nothing will be passed on to that page other than node id and destination.

Comment: I just changed type from submit to link and added #href and [#options]['path'] and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, if you get a chance to put a answer in to show how you did it that would be great, and I'm sure would help future visitors

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in your custom module.

For Example -

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

  if ($op == "delete") {
    // If no user object is supplied, the access check is for the current user.
    if (empty($account)) {
      $account = $GLOBALS['user'];
    }
    // You can add your own condition check here...
    return user_access("delete content", $account) ? NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW : NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;

}
```